# On click on a check box is not working properly working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am new to asp .net MVC 4.

I am doing a small application.
I have one check box, once I will click on that check box then I should able to display two text box. I have made them these two text box as invisible with the help of `display:none`

**Coding**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
         $('#checkbox1').click(function setCompleteStatus() {
            $('#textboxshow').show();
         });
      });


 <tr class="gridAlternateRow">
      <td>
       <span style="color:red;">*</span>&nbsp;Name
      </td>
      <td colspan="4">
          <div class="row">
               @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.txtfirstName)
                 <br />
                  @Html.CheckBox("txtChangePrintName", new { @id = "checkbox1", @onclick = "setCompleteStatus()" })
                        <br />
                   <div id="textboxshow">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.txtfirstName, new { style = "display:none;", @readonly = "readonly" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.txtLastName, new { style = "display:none;" })
                  </div> 
         </div>
     </td>
</tr>
```

As I am new to mvc 4 so I am not able to do ? Will any one help me out ?

Comment: What is the error are you getting?

Comment: Try using `$('#textboxshow :input').show();` instead

Comment: i am not getting any error ,it is running but while clicking on check box two text box's are not coming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$('#checkbox1').click(function () {
  $('input[type="text"]').show();
});
```

and remove `@onclick = "setCompleteStatus()` from the `@Html.CheckBox()` method

Comment: thanks for your support...i have done same what you suggest but still it is not  working

Comment: Please refer [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s1g9287v/) - uses `.toggle()` instead

Comment: what you suggest it is working how i can toggle for specific textbox.Means i want to do only two text box toggle not others how to do this.

Comment: what you suggest it is working how i can toggle for specific textbox.Means i want to do only two text box will be in toggle form(these two should will be visible and invisible) not others how to do this.

Comment: I suggest you give the textboxes a class name and use that as the selector - e.g. `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.txtfirstName, new { @class = "hidden" })` and then use `$('.hidden').show();`. This way you can style the class as `display:none`.

Answer (score 0):

You are making `div` visible instead of `textboxes` and close your `<script>` tag. And as you are binding click event to checkbox then no need to set `onclick` attribute for checkbox.

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
         $('#checkbox1').click(function(){
              $('#textboxshow').children().toggle();
         });
      });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for your support...i have done same what you suggest but still it is not  working

Comment: do you see any console errors on browser and have you included jQuery library to your html page? Please post jsfiddle link with your problem statement, that way I can help you better.

Comment: Try replacing `$('#textboxshow input').show();` with `$('#textboxshow').children().show();` as I am not sure if you are getting input inside textboxshow div

Comment: will u tell me one thing after clicking 2 text box  is displaying,when i will again click on that check box it should in invisible form

Comment: See my updated answer, this will toggle the textarea when you change value of checkbox

Comment: can u give me some suggestion how i can retrieve a single field value from database  and put in my textbox

Comment: use text box id and put value like `$('#texboxIdOfYourBox').val(ValueFromDB)`

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#checkbox1').click(function() {
        $('#txtfirstName').show();
        $('#txtLastName').show();
     });
  });
```

and remove `@onclick = "setCompleteStatus()"` from `@html.checkbox()` because it will be handled by Jquery only.

Comment: Wow! should I respond the same way you do?

Comment: thanks for your support...i have done same what you suggest but still it is not  working

Comment: @Cool...instead of $('#checkbox1').click(function() {});..try $('#checkbox1').change(function() {});

Comment: Thanks for ur support...Mr Exception